# Is there any way to select a cell by clicking the object above it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a protected sheet with many objects over it. Is there any way I can select a cell by clicking the object directly above it? In other words, a way to click "through" the object onto the cell underneath it?

Comment: what kind of object you have in mind? shape, chart, form formats?

Comment: Picture. I was thinking if I could just click past the drawing layer I would be fine, but I can't find anything related to that.

Answer (score 2):

Considering there are no protection (otherwise it would make this suggestion to long and to complicated) you could:

1) create this simple macro in any standard module in VBA project:

```
Sub left_top_cell()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Select
End Sub
```

2) set the action of you picture (right click and something like 'assign a macro') and choose on the list our macro `left_top_cell`.

3) as a result you'll get selected cell which is below top-left corner of your shape. If needed you could change into bottom-right.

**Important!** tried and tested for pictures according to your comment.

Comment: Note: this only works if the shape name is <= 30 characters long, as Application.Caller chops at 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be very simple. I've tried it. I don't know if it applies to your situation.

1) in Design mode, double click on this picture
2) it takes you to eg: - Private Sub picture1_Click()

```
                     End Sub
```

3) just type between Private Sub and End Sub - range("A1").select - you can mention the address of any cell that you want, then the rest of your code can follow.

this will select the cell as soon as you click the picture and then run rest of the code.

Hope it helps.....